# How to perform sorting with circular series in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table with 3 columns (id, date, number)
number is a value which starts from 1 till 9999. Once it hits 9999 all series is changed to negative numbers (aka -1 to -9999) and it starts over from 1.

This is my query:

```
select id,date,number
from table
order by date DESC, abs(number) DESC
```

This gives the following result:

```
26    3.1.17      5
25    3.1.17      4
21    2.1.17    -9999
3     2.1.17    -9998
4     2.1.17    -9997
51    2.1.17      3
6     2.1.17      2
7     2.1.17      1
10    1.1.17    -9996
```

Basically sort the data by date and then by the number column.
Since the sort is by date it works most of the time however in dates where the number is changed from `-9999` to `1` the order is messed up.

**This should be the result**

```
id   date    number
26    3.1.17      5
25    3.1.17      4
51    2.1.17      3
6     2.1.17      2
7     2.1.17      1
21    2.1.17    -9999
3     2.1.17    -9998
4     2.1.17    -9997
10    1.1.17    -9996
```

How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
select id,date,number
from a_table
order by date desc, number < 0, abs(number) desc
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to make sure the positive numbers are sorted first.

This can be achieved using an expression in the order by:

```
select id, date, number
from the_table
order by date, 
         case 
            when number > 0 then 1
            else 2
         end, --<< this makes the positive numbers come first
         abs(number) desc
```

Answer (score 0):

```
order by date DESC, 
         CASE WHEN number > 0  -- SORT THE POSITIVES
              THEN number 
              ELSE NULL -- dont need it, NULL is the default if you omit ELSE
         END DESC,
         number ASC  -- SORT THE NEGATIVES
```